# Can we use machine learning models / deep learning models for longitudinal data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mixed-model

I am analysing a cohort study done on a certain disorder. It has around 80 baseline variables and a binary response variable indicating the presence or absence of the disease, collected at 4 time points. I can use generalised linear mixed models (logistic mixed effects models) to analyse the longitudinal data.
However, I was wondering whether I could apply machine learning techniques or deep learning techniques to model the data.